# $B^2H^2\times(A+1)+(2B-H^2)\times(A-1)\over BH$ Factorisation and Reduction

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I would like to simplify the following expression:

$$B^2H^2\times(A+1)+(2B-H^2)\times(A-1)\over BH$$

I tried to do:
$$\implies{(-A-1)\times(H^2(-B^2+1)+2B)+\frac{1}{H})\over BH}$$
$$\implies {H^2B^2A-\frac{2AB}{oH}\mp AH^2+H^2B + 2B \mp H^2 \over BH}$$

I don't know how to go further,

The goal is to use the fact that $H^2$ is regardless of the sign to factorize it with the rest and The final expression to become $$[EXP]\over B$$

regards, thank you for helping me.

EDIT:

I think I found something:
$$- H^2 (A+1) -(A-1)[H \times (1-B)^2 \times \mp H] \over B H$$

$$\pm H \times (A+1) -(A-1)[H \times (1-B)^2] \over B$$

$$\pm H \times ((A+1) -(A-1)(1-B)^2) \over B$$

$$\implies{\pm \frac{H}{B} \times (AB^2 +B^2 +2A)}$$

tell me if it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your term can be simplified to $$\frac{(A-1) \left(B^2 H^2+2 B-H^2\right)}{B H}$$